# Too few arguments to pass to a function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to create an add to cart function. But I'm getting this error when i click on the "add to cart" icon/button which i have set.

`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::getAddToCart(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

I have seen many similar questions but most of the answers look complicated and does not seem to similar to my issues. Again, I am new in Laravel and would need the simplest form of explanation. Below are my ProductController and route codes

ProductController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cart;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('shop', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->route('shop');
    }
}
```

route for add to cart function:

`Route::get('/add-to-cart', ['uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart', 'as' => 'product.addToCart']);`

P/S: I am using Laravel 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your route as below

```
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart', 'as' => 'product.addToCart']);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! but is there any explanations to why do i need to add {id} in my route?